# How can I determine where an error occurred in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am running a simple React app w/ webpack in development mode as follows:

> webpack -w --mode development --config ./webpack.config.js

so that my code is not minified.  However I get a warning from React as follows:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.
> at **WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT** (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:4165:70)
> at div
> at **WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT** (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:4120:73)

The links it gives are to actual React library code, but I would like to know the code the developer wrote which caused the warning.

Normally React will pull up the developer's code, but in this case it does not.  Is there a way to find this easily?

I believe an error will normally show a stack trace but this is a warning so perhaps it is not possible?

I would like to atleast know the file which is causing the warning.

Comment: HI, can you post your webpack config?

Comment: `eval` usually points to the origin/file from which you get the error. `source-map` is good for production builds.

Comment: I'd recommend using eval for local development and false for prod - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: If you write the answer, please explain what eval does compared to source-map.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `eval-source-map` in development - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#development

> eval-source-map - Each module is executed with eval() and a SourceMap
> is added as a DataUrl to the eval(). Initially it is slow, but it
> provides fast rebuild speed and yields real files. Line numbers are
> correctly mapped since it gets mapped to the original code. It yields
> the best quality SourceMaps for development.

For production, `none`/`source-map` is a good place to start with.

> source-map - A full SourceMap is emitted as a separate file. It adds a
> reference comment to the bundle so development tools know where to
> find it.

Comment: I am currently using `source-map`.  Are you suggesting that `eval-source-map` will provide better debugging?

Comment: I find the amount of options for this property a bit crazy ... https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ ... I have a simple app I want to know where the error is.  The reference is like reading a dictionary for the same word spelled 20 ways.